# link helpers properties to a div in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm actually struggling with something simple; I want to my helper to be executed on the template "fullArticle".

I've tried to warp the tempate into a div, but it's not correct to use name HTML attribute on div. So I tried with a class, still nothing on the console.

I would be able to write something like this on my helper:

```
'.article': function(){...}
```

or better, use a data HTML attribute

```
'[data-name="article"]': function(){...}
```

or even directly target the template name (what i'm trying to do in the code below:

```
fullArticle: function(){...}
```

**fullArticle.html**

```
<template name="fullArticle">
    <div class="article">
    {{_id}}
    <h1>Full article {{title}}</h1>
    <h3><small>{{date}}</small></h3>
    <p>{{content}}</p>
    </div>
</template>
```

**fullArticle.js**

```
if (Meteor.isClient){
  Template.fullArticle.helpers({
    fullArticle: function(){
      console.log("id is : " + this._id);
      //return Articles.findOne({_id: id});
    }
  });
}
```

**routes.js**

```
Router.route(':categoryName/article/:_id', function(){
    this.render('fullArticle', {
        data: function(){
            return {_id: this.params._id};
        }
    });
});
```

Do you know how to make it work, or propose a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below you can find `typical schema` how to get data from database and display on client side. Please use it as inspiration.

On the server side create publish function:

```
Meteor.publish('article',function(articleId){
  check(articleId, String);
  return Articles.find({_id:articleId})
})
```

#### routes.js

```
Router.route(':categoryName/article/:_id',{
   name:'full.article',
   template: 'fullArticle',
   waitOn: function () {
    return Meteor.subscribe( 'article', this.params._id ),
   },
   data : function(){
     return Articles.findOne( { _id: this.params._id } ) 
   }
})
```

#### fullArticle.html

```
<template name="fullArticle">
    <div class="article">
    {{_id}}
    <h1>Full article {{title}}</h1>
    <h3><small>{{date}}</small></h3>
    <p>{{content}}</p>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Is that a good practice to access to the DB from the route? Isn't is better to do it from the helper? Thanks for your answer btw

Comment: Kuba's solution is solid, have the route return the actual document, not just it's `_id`. It's also fine to use a template helper to return data in most cases but when you've got a route with an _id parameter it's more common to do it in the `data:` function of the route.